# Is there a better way to confirm multiple validation messages with Selenium Webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to automate a UI page which will display multiple validation messages if the required fields are not populated.

What is the best way to make sure all are displayed?

There are 7 different error messages

```
<span for="JobTitle">The Job Title field is required.</span>
<span for="JobReference">The Reference field is required.</span>
<span for="LocationSelect">The Location field is required.</span>
<span for="ReportsTo">The Reports To field is required.</span>
<span for="DirectReports">The Direct Reports To field is required.</span>
<span for="DepartmentSelect">The Department field is required.</span>
<span for="Type">The Type field is required.</span>
```

Would I need to do something similar like this for each message?

```
public static void Validation()
   {
    Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/section[2]/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/span/span"));
   }
```

Comment: I think it's better to find by tags like `id`, `class` and `for` etc. Otherwise your test will break if there are some UI changes.

Comment: Likewise, `html/body/section[2]/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/span/span` is extremely brittle.

Answer (score 0):

`Driver.Instance.FindElement();` will give you the first element that match this `xpath`. If you need to check more than one you need to use `FindElement`

```
Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("html/body/section[2]/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/span/span"));
```

If you want to check they are all displayed iterate over them with loop

```
public static bool Validation()
{
    IList<IWebElement> messages = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("html/body/section[2]/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/span/span"));
    foreach (IWebElement message in messages)
    {
        if (!message.Displayed)
        {
            return false; // one of the messages isn't displayed
        }
    }

    return true; // all the messages are displayed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **CollectionAssert.AreEqual()** to compare the validation messages.